# Error while running flutter project on IOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have been trying to run my flutter project on my MacBook Air 12.1 but getting following error.

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried cleaning up pods file or deleting pods file and reinstall pods, but facing the same issue since yesterday.

Below is my flutter doctor for the version I am using

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

If I run the same project on Xcode I am getting a different error as follows:

```
flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/share_plus-3.0.4/ios/Classes/FLTSharePlusPlugin.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command in your terminal

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

and after Re-install dependencies

> arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: Getting the same error after running the second command

Comment: run this command :- arch -x86_64 pod update

Comment: Showing the same error